# Accessing the index position of an object within an Array

Tags: java, arrays, object, indexing

Hi I want to know how to access the index position of an object within an array. I have a search method which searchs for the object I want, then once I have this I want to be able to retrieve its index position. My search method is as follows:

```
public megs find(String lName)      // find specified value
{
  int j;
  int location;
  for(j=0; j<nElems; j++){          // for each element
     if(a[j].getLast().equals(lName))       // found item?
        location=j;
     break;                 // exit loop before end
  }
  if(j==nElems)             // gone to end?
     return null;               // yes, can’t find it
   else
     return a[j];               // no, found it

  } // end find
```

I have tried using a separate method using the for loop and and returning the j but it always returns 0.

```
public static int get(String sk) {

  int j;
  for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)
     if(a[j].equals(sk))
       return j;   
   }
```

Comment: Why maintain a separate length attribute when you can use `a.length`? Have you checked to see if the first element in the array *always is* the element you're looking for (perhaps implying a bug elsewhere in your code if that's not expected behaviour)?

Answer (score 0):

At least this code here is definitively wrong:

```
for(j=0; j<nElems; j++){          // for each element
 if(a[j].getLast().equals(lName))       // found item?
    location=j;
 break;                 // exit loop before end
}
```

the `break` will *always* be executed, you should use this here instead:

```
for(j=0; j<nElems; j++){          // for each element
 if(a[j].getLast().equals(lName)) {       // found item?
    location=j;
    break;                 // exit loop before end
 }
}
```

Comment: This is a prime example of *why you should **always** use braces in loops and conditionals*.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class java1 {

static String a[]={"ak","jk","kl"};

public static int get(String sk){
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
        if(a[j].equals(sk)){
            return j;
        }
    }

    return -1;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x=get("jk");
    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

Comment: Only if the length of `a` never changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class java1 {

public static int get(String sk,String a[],int n){
    int j;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(a[j].equals(sk)){
            return j;
        }
    }

    return -1;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a[]={"ak","jk","kl"};
    int x=get("jk",a,3);
    System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

Comment: you can pass the array and the changing length as argument.

Comment: The array itself will always know how large it is, that's why all array objects have a public `length` attribute. Using (in this instance) `a.length` as the loop upper bound will *always* be more reliable than trying to keep track of the size manually.

Comment: I'm not the asker - I'm just trying to nudge you to improve your answer. You might also want to consider that code-only answers tend not to get upvoted. Explain (concisely) what your code is doing,  because while it might be obvious to you and I it's not necessarily obvious to other readers coming in from Google.

Comment: well I accept that. I shall keep that in mind in future.